# Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2016 - Two MSCRM database have same configuration - one works with good performance while the other works with low performance

Tags: sql, dynamics-crm

Suddenly the run time of the query running in Dynamics MSCRM database has increased rapidly  . There has been no change in indexing or any other configuration that existed earlier .A query used to take 30 secs as such to run and now it is taking more than 4 mins.

**Query:**

```
SELECT 
  Filterederi_salesengagement.eri_salesengagementnumber ,
  Filterederi_salesengagement.eri_name ,
  Filterederi_salesengagement.eri_salestrackname ,
  Filterederi_salesengagement.eri_salesstagename ,
  Filterederi_salesengagement.eri_statusofbusinessname ,
  Filterederi_salesengagement.eri_statusofsalesprocessname ,
  Filterederi_salesengagement.eri_totaldealvalue_base 
FROM 
  Filterederi_salesengagement
WHERE 
  Filterederi_salesengagement.eri_statusofbusinessname='Ongoin‌​g'
```

Comment: Hello yould you post the slow query and a sample of your data?

Comment: No change in configuration + performance degrades = there is more data and so the query takes longer. Or, a piece of hardware is failing causing the server to slow down

Comment: The CRM database which is performing well has is hosted in the same replica of server(hardware) where the CRM database with low performance is hosted. My first thought is the Filtered View performance which has been a bottleneck always.

Comment: @PeterRing - The query which takes time is a simple select query a shown below :          SELECT
  Filterederi_salesengagement.eri_salesengagementnumber
  ,Filterederi_salesengagement.eri_name
  ,Filterederi_salesengagement.eri_salestrackname
  ,Filterederi_salesengagement.eri_salesstagename
  ,Filterederi_salesengagement.eri_statusofbusinessname
  ,Filterederi_salesengagement.eri_statusofsalesprocessname
  ,Filterederi_salesengagement.eri_totaldealvalue_base
FROM
  Filterederi_salesengagement
WHERE 
Filterederi_salesengagement.eri_statusofbusinessname='Ongoing'

Comment: Sales Engagement is the View where I am trying to pull the data which in fact takes data from a table and few other inbuilt CRM functions(user related)

Comment: Same infrastructure, same amount of data, same number of users, same number of other processes? Something must have changed, something must be different between the environments.

Comment: Added query posted to comments

Answer (score 0):

The performance slows down if the AsyncOperationBase table becomes too large. Try running the following script on your Organization_MSCRM DB.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT name from sys.indexes
WHERE name = N'CRM_AsyncOperation_CleanupCompleted')
      DROP Index AsyncOperationBase.CRM_AsyncOperation_CleanupCompleted
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX CRM_AsyncOperation_CleanupCompleted
ON [dbo].[AsyncOperationBase] ([StatusCode],[StateCode],[OperationType])
GO

while(1=1)
begin
declare @DeleteRowCount int = 10000
declare @rowsAffected int
declare @DeletedAsyncRowsTable table (AsyncOperationId uniqueidentifier not null primary key)
insert into @DeletedAsyncRowsTable(AsyncOperationId)
Select top (@DeleteRowCount) AsyncOperationId from AsyncOperationBase
where 
  OperationType in (1, 9, 12, 25, 27, 10) 
  AND StateCode = 3 
  AND StatusCode in (30, 32)

 select @rowsAffected = @@rowcount 
 delete poa from PrincipalObjectAccess poa 
   join WorkflowLogBase wlb on
    poa.ObjectId = wlb.WorkflowLogId
   join @DeletedAsyncRowsTable dart on
    wlb.AsyncOperationId = dart.AsyncOperationId
delete WorkflowLogBase from WorkflowLogBase W, @DeletedAsyncRowsTable d
where 
  W.AsyncOperationId = d.AsyncOperationId             
 delete BulkDeleteFailureBase From BulkDeleteFailureBase B, @DeletedAsyncRowsTable d
where 
  B.AsyncOperationId = d.AsyncOperationId
delete BulkDeleteOperationBase From BulkDeleteOperationBase O, @DeletedAsyncRowsTable d
where 
  O.AsyncOperationId = d.AsyncOperationId
delete WorkflowWaitSubscriptionBase from WorkflowWaitSubscriptionBase WS, @DeletedAsyncRowsTable d
where 
  WS.AsyncOperationId = d.AsyncOperationID 
 delete AsyncOperationBase From AsyncOperationBase A, @DeletedAsyncRowsTable d
where 
  A.AsyncOperationId = d.AsyncOperationId
/*If not calling from a SQL job, use the WAITFOR DELAY*/
if(@DeleteRowCount > @rowsAffected)
  return
else
  WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:02.000'
end
```

Comment: I ran the above query but unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: I checked the filtered views definition and found that the system generated function "fn_GetSharedRecordIdsForFilteredView" is causing the problem here . Any idea about this function which might have cause the performacne issue before